# Unable to create a lambda - error: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER

Tags: ruby, lambda

This is my code:

```
my_array = ["raindrops", :kettles, "whiskers", :mittens, :packages]

# Add your code below!
symbol_filter = lambda {|x| if(x.is_a? Symbol) puts x end}
```

[image]

I want to create a lambda which will filter for symbols in the array.

Comment: A screenshot is usually not necessary.

Comment: It's not necessary to tell us you're new or ask for forgiveness. If you've done a reasonably thorough search and ask the question well you'll have no problems.

Comment: @theTinMan - despit that, sh!t still happens. So, I play safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is as follows:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
```

And it is pointing at `puts`, which means `puts` is what was unexpected.

So the solutions are to give it what it expects

```
if ( x.isA? Symbol ) then puts x end

if ( x.isA? Symbol ); puts x end

if ( x.isA? Symbol )
  puts x
end
```

As a side, there is another syntax for one-liners like this

```
puts x if ( x.isA? Symbol )
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `if` conditions in one single line, you have to end your `if` header with a ';'. However I would highly recommend against those `if`s. Moreover you should write something like this:

```
if x.is_a?(Symbol)
  p x
end
```

or use the proper inline syntax:

```
p x if x.is_a?(Symbol)
```

Back to your problem, what do you want to achieve? Find all symbols in the array? Then you should use `select` on that array